# Spectrum color picker through PHP $_POST

Tags: php, jquery, html

My color picker called [Spectrum](https://bgrins.github.io/spectrum/) works fine, but I can't get it to send variables through $_POST.

JQ

```
   $("#acc").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) { this.value(color.toHexString()); },
});
$("#bgc").spectrum({
    color: "#f00",
    change: function(color) { this.value(color.toHexString()); },
});
```

HTML

```
<label for="s_cl">
  <li class="sett"><input name="acc" type='text' id="acc" /> Accent color</li>
</label>

<label for="bg_cl">
  <li class="sett"><input name="gbc" type='text' id="bgc" /> Background color</li>
</label>
```

PHP (submit.php)

```
if (isset ($_POST['acc'])) {
  echo $_POST['acc'];
} 

echo '<br>'; 

if (isset ($_POST['gbc'])) {
  echo $_POST['gbc'];
}
```

I gotta add that all other variables are being posted and displayed correctly. I need my Spectrum Color Picker variables to be sent through $_POST. Also, thats my header of form:

```
<form method="post" id="sett-form" action="submit.php">
```

Comment: input elements send data through the `value` property. My guess is this `spectrum` plugin isn't assigning data to the `value`

Comment: @SterlingArcher how then can I send variables through Spectrum plugin?

Comment: I don't know, I have not used spectrum. Assign the values. Google it, it can't be that hard.

Comment: given the fiddle sample the spectrum site has, you probably need `change: function(color) { this.value(color.toHexString()); }`  inside your .spectrum() call

Comment: @MarcB I got no errors after adding that to jQuery, but it doesn't seem to work. The variables are not being posted anyway

Comment: In the action of confirm the color, you should put some code like this : `$("#bcg").attr('value',color);`

Comment: @AngeloBerzacola I don't quite understand where should I place it in my JQ code

Comment: @Kajcioch i the action in you code that change the color. understood?

Comment: @AngeloBerzacola No, not at all.. Sorry

Comment: @AngeloBerzacola nevermind I got it! Upvoting your comments, it's just me being dumb

Answer (score 0):

Apparently adding `change: function(color) { this.value(color.toHexString()); },` to spectrum call in jQuery call makes variables POSTable